# Using JavaScript to display hidden divs

Tags: javascript, css, class, html

I have a *class* of divs (there are 5 of them). In my CSS I have set that class to `display:none;`. Each div also has a unique *ID*. I want to use JS to make these divs appear individually.

something like this:

```
<style>
.hidden{
     display:none; }
</style>
<script>
function displayDiv1(){
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block"; }
function displayDiv2(){
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block"; }
</script>
<div class="hidden" id="div1">
<p>some stuff here</p>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="div2">
<p>some more stuff here</p>
</div>
```

Here's a jfiddle (not working) http://jsfiddle.net/DAzZT/

Is it possible to do something like this or do I have to individually declare each `div` `display:none;` using the `id` as opposed to the `class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is only `getElementById`, you will need to write `document.getElementById`. And make only one function to do the same job :

```
function showDiv(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    return false;
}
```

Call it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('your_div_id');">Show Div</a>
```

Comment: Good point, that will save me some time/space. I just wanted to make sure this will work on all browsers, this is typical behavior or will certain browsers be picky about how `display` is declared?

Comment: As i know, all borwser support `display` style ( exclude lynx ).

Comment: Actually the problem was that he wrapped the function into another function, making his `displayX` functions inaccessible from the global scope. You can find more details regarding that problem in my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13246583/1375293

Comment: @clentfort My brackets are at the end of the line, I didn't wrap a function in another one, or did I somehow that I'm not seeing?

Comment: jsfiddle does the wrapping automatically

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to put your functions in the correct scope, as you have done in your question, and use `document.getElementById`. Change the onLoad option on the left to no wrap(body)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for that. Like u said, u set display: none in your css and after that using jQuery u have $('#element').show(); - to show or $('#element').hide() to hide.

Answer (score 1):

try this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/DAzZT/1/)**

you should call it using document object

```
function display1(){
document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
}
function display2(){
 document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Comment: Aha! I did that kind of hastily. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is one error in your code, it is `document.getElementById` not `getElementById`.

Also you did one mistake in your fiddle. You selected to wrap your code into an `onLoad` function. This results in your actual JavaScript looking like this.

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    function display1(){
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
    }
    function display2(){
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block"; 
    }
});
```

Your function definitions are **inside** a function, they are not accessible in the global scope. So if you click on one of your links now it results in a `Uncaught ReferenceError`.

To fix this problem you can either set to not wrap your code into a function (on the left under choose framework the first drop down select `no wrap (head)` or `no wrap (body)`.

Or a better attempt is to add the functions to the global `window` object, keep the `onLoad` wrapping and modify your code to.

```
window.display1 = function(){
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
}
window.display2 = funnction(){
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, I didn't knwo that. I'm a noob to fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

try `document.getElementById` instead of `getElementById` in the javascript functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution :

```
<script>
    function display(num){
       document.getElementById('div'+num).style.display = "block";
       return false;
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="return display(1);">Open Div 1</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="return display(2);">Open Div 2</a>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EaEGP/) (I removed your `position:absolute` to let both divs be visible)